# Ruby on Rails select tags from hash

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a hash stored as a constant defined in application.rb

It looks a bit like this:

```
ITEMS = { "Item 1" => ['1 - sdfsdf', '2 - sdlfksdf'], "Item 2" => ['1 - lkfsdf', 2- dkfdjk']}
```

What I would like from this is one combo box with the options:
Item 1
Item 2

and a second combo box with the items in the array in the hash depending on the selection of the first.

Is there an easy way to do this with rails 3 (I am using JQuery)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the first box with the following:

```
<%= f.select :var_name, ITEMS.collect { |key, value| [key, key] } %>
```

Then, add an observer

```
<%= observe_field 'element_var_name',
      :url => { :action => "another_action_here" },
      :update => "div_tag_to_update",
      :with => "'selected='+ escape($('element_var_name').value)" %>
```

Be sure to adjust `element_var_name` and the action to your situation. The `another_action_here` action should render a view like this:

```
def call_ids_by_type
  @element_list = ITEMS[param[:selected].collect { |value| [value, value] }
  render :layout => false
end
```

The associated view should only contain the select field you want to add. Haven't tried it exactly, but I think this should work.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't entirely use what you said but I used the jQuery ajax calls etc. You definatly helped push me in the right direction.